# "example" vs "exemple" word usage

Tags: word-usage

I used to use it (*example*) with "a" but in this video
[Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ycr7dVH7EV4) (at 7:07)
[Link 2](https://youtu.be/YGOu-raM25k?t=427)
I watched an another variant (*exemple*). Is it a correct usage or a mistake?

Comment: video is not available

Comment: It's available. I've just checked it. If not, you can find it on youtube by searching "STEEP - Gameplay Walkthrough E3 2016 "

Comment: It's not available to us. It might be a country restriction or something.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is the result of a transcription error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean [this](https://youtu.be/YGOu-raM25k?t=427).

Yes, it is incorrect. That is a typo, it should be

> Here's another **example**.

There is this,

> [par exemple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/par%20exemple)
>   for example

You might hear or read this in the English language. But this is **not** what the speaker used in the video.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [Steep (video game)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steep_(video_game)) developers are in France. Looks like a translation error in the text, as *example* in French seems to be *exemple".

Comment: Yeah, I figured something of the sort. I wouldn't say translation error though, since the speaker is speaking in English. More like a subbing or transcription error. Yes, exemple is French for example.

Comment: Sorry you are right, its a transcription error.